# Ember throwing Cannot set property 'dataSourceBinding' of undefined when trying to use a model on Index Route

Tags: ember.js

I am just starting with the bare-bones starter kit, trying to do something very basic.

In my end result app, there will be a list of categories and subcategories that serve as the nav for the app. My solution being an Ember novice, and just to get something working, was to start with the tutorial by Tom Dale and try moving from there. So, I set up a variable to hold some dummy models to use just to get something on the screen.

When I try to run the app, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dataSourceBinding' of undefined`

EDIT--
I have tried moving the declaration of the categories variable to the top of the app.js file, but still get the same error.

My question is really two questions:

1. What am I missing/doing incorrectly?
2. I realize that ultimately setting up the app with the categories as a model on the index action is probably not the best approach. This list needs to be dynamic as it will be configurable by users. Is there a better way to have this dynamic nav included in the main template?

`app.js`:

```
MSSWApp = Ember.Application.create();

MSSWApp.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('categories', function() {
    this.resource('category', { path: ':category_id' });
  });
});

MSSWApp.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return categories;
  }
});

var categories = [{
  id: 1,
  title: "Auto & Mechanical"
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: "Beauty & Fashion"
}, {
  id: 3,
  title: "Careers & Education"
}];
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test Ember Model on Index</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h1>Categories</h1>
    <ul>
      {{#each in model}}
      <li>
        <h2>
          {{#link-to 'category' this}}
            {{title}}
          {{/link-to}}
        </h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub 1-1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub 1-2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub 1-3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <!-- to activate the test runner, add the "?test" query string parameter -->
  <script src="tests/runner.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try wrapping the `categories` array in `Em.A( // Array here )` to turn `categories` into an Ember array. Also, no need for the `in` - you can use `{{#each model}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the template needs a name, otherwise Ember assumes that's the application template.

setting up the script tag like this:

`<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">`

did the trick